# Auto Comment Compile Time Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a project which is full of compile time errors? Is there is any feature in Visual Studio to auto comment all Compile Time Errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can highlight a block of code with your mouse and then press CTRL-K-C to comment out the hightlighted block.

You can reverse this action by highlighting the block of code and pressing CTRL-K-U.

There is no short cut or utility to comment out lines of code that do not compile; but it make help to comment out further 'down' in the file to limit the effect of cascading compiler errors (for example, a missing variable declaration will cascade to each occurence of the variable further down).

Comment: There is no 3rd party tool that I'm aware of.  However, it may be possible to write a VS macro to do part of the task.  Getting someone inspired enough to write such a macro would be more challenging than simply using the keyboard short cuts I identified for you...

Answer (score 1):

Thstas not possible but you need to click on each erro of error window and have to resolve or need to comment it by ur self only. for common eeror you can make use of replace window and make them comment.